# How many elements $T \in \mathcal P(A)$ are there so that $T \mathcal R S$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{1,2,3,...,2000\}$and $\mathcal P(A)$ the power set of $A$ Let $\mathcal R$ be the relation on $\mathcal P(A)$ defined by $B\mathcal RC$ if $B \cup C=A$. Now let $S=\{1,2,3,...,237\}$. I'm trying to find how many elements $T \in \mathcal P(A)$ are there so that $T \mathcal R S$. My attempt is that $S$ is fixed so for $T \cup S=A$ to be true I can assume that $\{238,239,...,2000\} \subseteq T$ so then the answer should be how many subsets their are of $S$ which is $2^{237}$. Does this make sense? Is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense and it's correct.

Comment: Yes this is correct

Comment: "how many subsets their are of $S$" is a bit unclear. But I think you're thinking correctly. The problem is about the number of the ways that you can add some elements of $S$ to $\{238,\dots,2000\}$, which is exactly the number of subsets of $S$.